# SyntaxGenerator.IdentifierName escapes minimally qualified primitive types

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

When I try to create an identifier using the Roslyn `SyntaxGenerator.IdentifierName` for a primitive type, it adds an escape to the `Identifier.Text`.

```
var generator = SyntaxGenerator.GetGenerator(document);

// genericTypeArg.Identifier.ValueText = "@double"
var genericTypeArg = generator.IdentifierName("double");

// generic.Identifier.ValueText = "IEnumerable<@double>"
var generic = generator.GenericName("IEnumerable", genericTypeArg);
```

Any ideas how to create the type identifier without it being escaped?

Edit:

Would this be a valid way to test?

```
var typeExp = typeSymbol.SpecialType == SpecialType.None
    ? _generator.IdentifierName(typeSymbol.ToDisplayString(symbolDisplayFormat));
    : _generator.TypeExpression(typeSymbol.SpecialType)
var generic = _generator.GenericName("IEnumerable", typeExp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `IdentifierName()` is exactly that – the name of an identifier.

You asked for an identifier named `double`, and it gave you a valid syntax for that.

You need the [`SpecialType` overload](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Editing/SyntaxGenerator.cs,1665):

```
generator.TypeExpression(SpecialType.System_Double)
```

Comment: The thing is that I am getting the type information from an ITypeSymbol and if I do `generator.GenericName("IEnumerable", typeSymbol)` and the typeSymbol happens to be a primitive (double for example) then the generic created will be `IEnumerable<System.Double>`. To clean this up so I just get back `double`, I tried to do `generator.GenericName("IEnumerable", generator.IdentifierName(typeSymbol.ToDisplayString(SymbolDisplayFormat.MinimallyQualifiedFormat)))`, but this escapes built in keywords.

Comment: So how do I write this so that the type printed uses the keyword of a built in type or the minimally qualified format of a custom type? Thanks!

Comment: I edited the original post to ask if my proposed way to do this will work.

Comment: @LGreenberger: You should just use the non-primitive typenames only, then use the Simplifier to automatically simplify.